# How to stack data frame factors duplicating row content

Tags: r, dataframe

I've used cast to get the following data frame:

```
> df1 = data.frame(start=LETTERS[1:5],end=LETTERS[2:6],runif(5, 1, 8),runif(5, 1, 8),runif(5, 1, 8),runif(5, 1, 8))
> colnames(df1) <- c("start", "end", "-1","0","1","2")
> df1
  start end       -1        0        1        2
1     A   B 3.618251 7.987927 5.055789 6.751314
2     B   C 6.021783 6.726739 7.818101 6.587156
3     C   D 2.012107 6.250554 3.988633 4.626493
4     D   E 6.315417 1.358453 6.544792 5.962934
5     E   F 1.147231 5.398415 2.521553 1.087538
```

With that starting point I'd like to get the following. 
In the data frame below the two factor columns are merged, duplicating the rows.
I'm hoping there is a simple solution, but I've not been a able work anything out:

```
    loc  type       -1        0        1        2
1     A start 3.618251 7.987927 5.055789 6.751314
2     B   end 3.618251 7.987927 5.055789 6.751314
3     B start 6.021783 6.726739 7.818101 6.587156
4     C   end 6.021783 6.726739 7.818101 6.587156
5     C start 2.012107 6.250554 3.988633 4.626493
6     D   end 2.012107 6.250554 3.988633 4.626493
7     D start 6.315417 1.358453 6.544792 5.962934
8     E   end 6.315417 1.358453 6.544792 5.962934
9     E start 1.147231 5.398415 2.521553 1.087538
10    F   end 1.147231 5.398415 2.521553 1.087538
```

Appreciate any help.

EDIT: I'm going to marked this as answered however it seems this approach does not work if the starting data frame is the result of a `cast(...)`.  I'll open this variation as another question.

EDIT 2: The issue I was running into was caused by using `cast(...)` from `reshape` library rather than `dcast(...)` from `reshape2` library.

Comment: Maybe ` melt(df1, id.vars=3:ncol(df1))`?

Comment: you prbly shld put that as an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just use `melt`:

```
library(reshape2) # I assume you already have that loaded since you mention cast
out <- melt(df1, id.vars=3:ncol(df1))
out
#          -1        0        1        2 variable value
# 1  2.618269 2.762658 1.711484 7.960830    start     A
# 2  5.003830 5.165788 3.263027 4.510824    start     B
# 3  7.695860 3.234819 5.943346 4.259366    start     C
# 4  2.767426 6.995359 3.998726 1.254995    start     D
# 5  4.116167 7.072667 1.924826 4.212113    start     E
# 6  2.618269 2.762658 1.711484 7.960830      end     B
# 7  5.003830 5.165788 3.263027 4.510824      end     C
# 8  7.695860 3.234819 5.943346 4.259366      end     D
# 9  2.767426 6.995359 3.998726 1.254995      end     E
# 10 4.116167 7.072667 1.924826 4.212113      end     F
```

If the row order is important (which I assume it must be), you can add a step like the following:

```
out[order(ave(as.character(out$variable), out$variable, FUN = seq_along)), ]
#          -1        0        1        2 variable value
# 1  2.618269 2.762658 1.711484 7.960830    start     A
# 6  2.618269 2.762658 1.711484 7.960830      end     B
# 2  5.003830 5.165788 3.263027 4.510824    start     B
# 7  5.003830 5.165788 3.263027 4.510824      end     C
# 3  7.695860 3.234819 5.943346 4.259366    start     C
# 8  7.695860 3.234819 5.943346 4.259366      end     D
# 4  2.767426 6.995359 3.998726 1.254995    start     D
# 9  2.767426 6.995359 3.998726 1.254995      end     E
# 5  4.116167 7.072667 1.924826 4.212113    start     E
# 10 4.116167 7.072667 1.924826 4.212113      end     F
```

The `ave` step creates an index to order by.

```
ave(as.character(out$variable), out$variable, FUN = seq_along)
#  [1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
```

Comment: Base R goodness would be: `data.frame(stack(lapply(df1[1:2],as.character),),df1[-(1:2)])`

Comment: Thanks the issue I was running into was caused by using `cast(...)` from `reshape` library rather than `dcast(...)` from `reshape2` library.